# How to pass a url title in a form action in django

Tags: python, django

sorry for newbie question, I'm learning django and ran into a problem.

I'm trying to pass a page title to url that will searched for in views for .md file with name of that title. (Page's title is coming up dynamically from other function in views, i.e {{ title }}).

HTML:

```
<form action="{% url 'edit' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group mt-4">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Edit page</button>
</div>
```

urls.py:

```
path("wiki/edit/", views.edit_page, name="edit")
```

views.py:

```
def edit_page(request, page):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request,"encyclopedia/edit_page.html", {
            "pagename": page,
            "html": markdown2.markdown(util.get_entry(page))
        })
```

What is the best practice for this. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

only add this `/<str:page>` to your path it means to put any string at this part of url and you will get this string in your page parameter in your view function

```
path("wiki/edit/<str:page>", views.edit_page, name="edit")
```

and for the form action put    `{%url 'edit' title %}`

Comment: for now I solved it as by putting title of the page as get-params. I actually tried your solution before, but django trows an error: `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'edit' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['wiki/(?P<page>[^/]+)/edit$']`

Comment: @blur are you sure you made it like this ```{% url 'edit' title %}``` not like this ```{% url 'edit' %}```

Comment: yeah, this time `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'edit' with keyword arguments '{'page': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['wiki/edit/(?P<page>[^/]+)$']
`

Comment: @blur this means that your title string is empty. Where do you get it from. Show me your code I know this project from CS50W.

Comment: `{% block title %}
 {{ pagename }}
{% endblock %}
`

Comment: @blur there is differences between the context and the template blocks use ```{% url 'edit' pagename %}```

Answer (score 0):

You have just missed by a bit,only part you need to update is your html template and your urls.py

```html
<form action="{% url 'edit' page=title %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group mt-4">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Edit page</button>
  </div>
```

your urls.py should be as:

```
urls.py path("wiki/edit/(?P<page>.+?)/$", views.edit_page, name="edit")
```

Note that this method is ideal in case you are passing title with spaces or characters